# What part is this? Circular threading spool gear, about 10 mm diameter

Tags: replacement-parts, part-identification

How should I describe this part which looks like a small gear so that I can research replacements?

[image: image of a pulley]

This came with my FLSUN 3D printer, which may be based on a Prusa design.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. It's the driven gear for the belt which either drives the X-axis or Y-axis depending on to which drive motor it's attached. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks I just realized how unclear that was. I was asking the product name of this part. So that I could do my own research and find where to purchase a replacement. My 3D printer kit was missing one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a timing belt pulley.

Specifically, is a GT2 timing pulley, 2 mm pitch (between teeth), 6 mm wide. The drive diameter is measured by the number of teeth (16 in this case) , the shaft diameter (bore) is measured in mm.

The 'GT2' part refers to the tooth profile, some other examples are shown half way down [this page](https://www.pfeiferindustries.com/timing-belt-identification-and-replacement).

Comment: More specifically, it is a 16 teeth GT2 timing belt pulley.

Answer (score 1):

It is an "aluminum timing  pulley"

https://www.google.com/search?psb=1&tbm=shop&q=aluminum%20timing%20pulley&ved=0CAMQr4sDKAFqFwoTCMis1KHmiuMCFRoMswAdMqUElxAB

https://www.ebay.com/i/152446519860?chn=ps&var=453435947176